# Passing POJO class, object to another POJO

Tags: java, oop

I am sure this question might have been asked couple of times here but I am not understanding what query I should use.
What I want to do is, Passing POJO to another POJO where parameter could be dynamic

like example below

```
Class DataPOJO{
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I want to make another POJO where I can pass value like

```
RequestmakerPOJO request = new RequestmakerPOJO(authorisationObject, dataPOJO, DataPOJO);
```

Where dataPOJO would be object I created and DataPOJO.class it's structure, later I can pass any kind of pojo to this new Requestmaker class with it's structure definition and object just like. `HashMap<ObjectType, ObjectType2>`

But I want only 1 Object type to be passed and then it's object. I am new at java so I don't know what to call these scenarios. Please help me out with the query or solution.

:) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `RequestmakerPOJO` as a generic class:

```
class RequestmakerPOJO<T> {
    ...
}
```

Now you can use `T` as a type wherever you want. For example, the constructor can be

```
RequestmakerPOJO(AuthPOJO auth, T data) {
    ...
}
```

To declare a variable

```
RequestmakerPOJO<DataPOJO> request = new RequestmakerPOJO<>(auth, data);
```

For more details, research generics in Java.